What's the strongest material known to humanity that we could use to make Powered Armor Plates?
I've been working on this idea for years now and I'm constantly wondering if all of even most of it is "realistic"/Hard enough. One concern I'm having is my Power Armor. It's built upon having multiple layers of protection much like suits of knights armor which made the most sense to me but it's the outermost layer of protection that is giving me pause.
My Powered Armor Suits are basically walking Tanks, so I'm using tanks as a basis for their armor.
I've always figured a Tungsten/Titanium Alloy would work best for protection from bullets, shrapnel, rail gun glances, and lasers but I know things can't really go 1-1.
Would this particular alloy work as an all around protection for those specific things or is there something else out there that would be better for that role?
For reference my Powered Armor looks similar to this. I just wish he had a helmet 

For some people who are still confused, when I say Powered Armor I mean Powered Armor aka this. https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PoweredArmor
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powered_exoskeleton
Space Marine Suits from 40 K, https://www.halopedia.org/MJOLNIR_Powered_Assault_Armor from Halo and so on. A wearable suit of technology advanced armor.
Not Mech Suit aka this, 

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

All armor is a trade off there is no single best, diffrent types of armor protect against diffrent things. there are also diffrent armor phislosphies, like reactive armor which is good once and needs to be replaced afterwards, but protects against things nothing else can. also strong, tough, and ahard are all very diffrent things please be more specific. this may help you inderstand https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BHZALtqAjeM

Welcome! While there is a reasonable question here, it's an easily researchable answer. Please add some links to articles you have read about the subject and specify where they haven't answered your question.


I doubt you'd have much hope against actual bombs. 2) Tungsten is very dense, so dunno why you'd think about it 3) There's no reason to use an alloy instead of ceramics, or better composite. 4) Outer layer wouldn't have to be toughest. It could be reflective, ablative, or camouflage.


I think by bombs I ment shrapnel, I have other layers to the armor to protect against other forms of attack like the shockwave of said bombs, I'm mostly concerned with the outside layer because that's the one that's going to take up the brunt of the punishment. Also I thought about Reactive Armor Plates but those wouldn't work really well in a Post Apocalyptic setting, hard to replace & all that. They'd be used for more specialist suits & missions. Also most of the links I have are years old & I don't have all of them anymore  I'm going from memory here. Should I post the whole armor up?

Nobody has been wearing metal armor since a long time ago. If the American army does not use metal armor for its soldiers, there is no reason to believe that anybody here could possibly provide a better solution without going against the Official Secrets Act of their country.

This is Powered Armor, meaning it's able to use heavier metal plates than standard military units. Besides metal armor is better at staying intact after multiple hits unlike Ceramics. This is a setting where every price of equipment is valuable, they're not going to use something that can only withstand 2-3 hits vs something that can equally withstand far more punishment.

What's the budget available and how many soldiers are expecting to be encapsulated?

Budget when these suits were in production was practically limitless because the military was running the government system seeing as Humanity was going around conquering planets all throughout the Galaxy. As for how many soldiers, billions.

Then you'll run out of (eg.)  tungsten from Earth, but lots of planets is more feasible.

@Altarious the way you write about alloying metals gives me the impression that you think of alloys like "10% of metal A + 90% of metal B will give me an alloy with 10% characteristics A and 90% characteristics B", but that's not how alloys work. The characteristics of an alloy of 2 (or more) components can be dramatically different to the characteristics of its components.

Well no, that's not how I think it works. I know that alloying is meant to give different properties depending on the mixtures, percentages of certain metals and chemicals and so on. Steel for example is stronger than iron as well as more ductile making it more useful in a wider array of applications from body armor to tool steel. The reason I picked Tungsten is because it's dense and hard which is usually what you need to defeat bullets. It's also brittle which is why I figured Titanium would be a good partner because it makes it more ductile and saves on weight.

But ... that's my point. Just because titanium is more ductile than tungsten, adding a little titanium to tungsten would not necessarily create an alloy that's more ductile than pure tungsten. In fact you might end up creating something that's even less ductile ...

Then maybe I really don't understand how certain things work regarding alloying but I was under the impression that it usually combines the best properties of both materials with some compromises because it's not purely one or the other. Everything I've researched says it's good for certain applications but that's also why I asked here if there's something better.

Like this article here, https://tft-pneumatic.com/blog/tungsten-titanium-alloy/#:~:text=Composition%20of%20Tungsten%20Titanium%20Alloys&text=Tungsten%20provides%20the%20mixture%20with,of%2080%2D95%25%20tungsten. Says that Tungsten/Titanium has good yield strength, tensile strength, and compression capacity. Am I misunderstanding what that means by thinking that's good for armor?

I don't think this is a useful military concept. Cost/Usage factor appears to be low. Counter measure are potentially cheap and easy. If air can get inside, use gas. Put napalm on it and cook the person. Or just in case with any armor, just build a bigger bomb. What happens if the power runs out or fails? Unless you're trying to transport a VIP, there seem to be more problems than benefit.

Well militarys are looking into them for a variety of factors. They'll allow troops to carry more ammunition, more armor, and more equipment without getting fatigued. Ideally if the technology is improved upon over the centuries it'll be fully self contained and thus defended against gas attacks which makes sense when you can just have a built in gas mask system. As for cost usage factors, that's not entirely an issue when you can manufacture them for cheap by just using inexhaustible resources, must least until the apocalypse happens, then they'd be super rare war relics.

What's the point of armor that can't (e.g.) be pierced by an artillery shell if you need a meter of cushion to avoid dying from the concussion? There isn't a reason to have better armor than is necessary to keep one alive. Beware the [tag:hard-science] tag because it won't simply tell you the strongest armor possible, if properly respected it must consider useless overkill that is actually a liability as it would give the wearer, if anything, false hope. A good [tag:hard-science] answer would describe only what's needed for the purpose.

Honestly I'm confused about what is being said here.

@Escapeddentalpatient. How are your teeth today? :-)

Kinetic protection
Ceramic outperforms all other armors by a massive margin.
Armor is commonly measured in military science by its RHA-equivalency ratio. RHA, or rolled homogenous armor steel, is largely similar to WWII-era ship and tank armor. This ratio can be calculated as RHAe = RHA.Weight / ThisArmor.Weight for equal area and the same test projectile. Most projectiles have test data against RHA.
Different types of armor perform differently against chemical (RPGs), low- and medium-speed kinetic (rifles, guns), or high-speed kinetic (tank guns) threats. Most common is low-speed kinetic:

Hardened armor aluminum has a RHAe ratio of ~1.2. It's suited for some structural uses, e.g. vehicle bodies, but not frames.
Uranium and tungsten by themselves are in the range of 0.9-1.5 depending on the threat, due to their density.
Maraging steel such as AerMet is 1.4–1.6 — it depends; steel is more effective against hard projectiles.
Grade 5 titanium has a RHAe ratio of ~1.5.
Chobham — a British sandwich of silicon carbide ceramic between two steel plates — has a RHAe ratio of ~2.2.
An advanced metal matrix composite (MMC), composed of titanium carbide in titanium matrix, has claimed a ratio of 2.8–3.6 depending on the liner. This is the strongest armor that can also be structural.
ESAPI and XSAPI, which are boron carbide with Dyneema a.k.a. UHMWPE liner, both correspond to 4.2–5.0 RHAe.

Of course, ceramic armor has less multi-hit resistance than metal, and isn't as good structurally. Still, it's used for vehicles where it can be afforded.
Two layers, ceramic and liner, are weight-optimal for wearable powered armor. It's not going to protect against RPGs, no matter how many layers it has. RPGs can kill tanks unless they hit glacis, bottom front, turret front, or a reactive armor (ERA) brick. Even if the power armor has ERA, its normal armor won't be enough to stop the remaining disrupted jet.
RPG protection
…Unless they are literally walking tanks.
The lightest of modern main battle tanks, the Chinese Type 10, weighs about 44 metric tons. The heaviest, the Abrams, 68, and so do other EU tanks that all basically copy it due to STANAG requirements. Two indigent tanks, the Korean K2 and the yet-experimental Armata, are about 55 tons.
If your power armor is in the range of 40–70 tons per unit, you'll be best served by picking a MBT to base it on. However, due to a larger surface area, the mech's average armor thickness, or more accurately areal weight budget, will be lower, 2–4 times so.
With a weight budget that high, you'd want to protect against RPGs. That entails additional layers of liners, spaced armor, ERA, and possibly even slat armor. Armor cages are even more useful against drones.
"Chemical energy" (how shaped charges are known) protection is best provided by spacing out several materials. It's always very thick, including a lot of hollow spaces and plates at sharp angles to the projectile.

Tungsten and uranium
In general, armor materials work better (per unit weight) the lighter they are. An exception is high-speed kinetic threats. When hit by hypervelocity (1.5 km/s and faster) projectiles, materials behave almost like liquids.
Including a layer of very dense material helps dissipate the energy of a hypervelocity projectile, which themselves are made of uranium or tungsten, across the following armor layers. The backing layers are always much lighter, and can include perforated steel, fiberglass, and other materials that try to absorb the hit.
Such armor's utility is questionable. The only hypervelocity projectiles in use today are APFSDS rounds; you'll only find them fired by tanks and sometimes lighter IFVs. In a future-tech world, they could be more common, but, generally, normal armor also works against small ones.
However, even modern MBTs only have this protection for their turrent front and front lower hull — it's too heavy.  Due to that, it only helps in a duel-style tank-on-tank action. In modern wars, very few tanks have been lost in such a way; missiles and now drones are the primary killer.
But they're cool!
If you want to use superheavy materials for the cool factor, you'd have to limit them to a very small area. I can imagine a thick stack with tungsten being included in a hard chestplate. It's going to be great if such power-armored troops have a tradition of chivalrously shooting each other in the chest. But it won't be thick enough against a tank gun, and you can't armor all of the body to this level.
Shields
Medieval as they sound, shields are all around the place in modern warfare. Guns come with shields, and a tank's turret front is effectively its shield (it's stronger than any other part of the tank).
The heaviest armor can be placed in the shield. The shield can also be thick enough to actually include protection against chemical energy, i.e. shaped charges. You probably won't have enough time to block an APFSDS with a shield, but enough to block an incoming missile, which are normally subsonic. So spaced armor and ERA bricks are a perfect fit here.
The smaller the shield, the better it can protect. If you're going to quickly position it against a radar-detected threat, a round "buckler" is best. Or, a larger SWAT-like shield if you want full-arc protection, but it will have to be fairly thin (a 1.6*2.5 meter shield
This guy basically has two shields - no reason a power armored trooper couldn't carry at least one.

Actionable scheme
The company behind the metal-matrix composite, Exote Armour, hasn't been successful with it, and pivoted to sell it as wear plates. Their whitepaper on the armor material is still available via the Internet Archive.
While it didn't work out, it could make for a perfect material for power armor, since it can be made in complex shapes and still stay tough. It's basically titanium carbide grains (armor ceramic) packed in titanium. You want a durable liner behind it, and I'd pick aramid (Kevlar) over UHMWPE, for its thermal and fire resistance. Behind that liner would be padding for comfort and a temperature-controlled garment similar to a flightsuit.
For parts that need maximum protection, and can afford some extra thickness, like the chestplate, you might want to add ceramic plates on top of the MMC, to maximize protection per unit weight. They won't be structural, and will need replacement after being shot.
For the shield, if you use one, a combination of strong metal or MMC base and ceramic plates is perfect. Chobham is pretty much a ready-made shield. Note that it's twice heavier than pure ceramics, for the same protection, but it's much more multi-hit resistant.
Also, consider not armoring anything that doesn't have to be armored. For a mech, for instance (I place the cutoff between power armor vs mechs at whether the operator's limbs reach the weapon), the limbs can be reduced to bare metal structures with wires inside. Like how you don't armor the barrel of a gun or the working arms of an armored recovery vehicle.

Their protection is being too small to get hit - you just accept the few lucky shots, in exchange for a much lighter machine. Plus, they can be repaired or replaced. The less you protect, the better you can protect it.

I love this!! This is what I've been looking for someone who knows about how armor works and could help by cooking up something wearable IRL. I do plan on having Mechs so this helps out immensely. And so far this is another person saying that Composite Armor is the way to go. I have a question though about Tungsten, I know it's not used much in armor today because it's incredibly heavy and brittle, but if it's mixed with say Titanium in an alloy, and added as a layer in this Ceramic Composite Armor could that be effective RPG protection seeing as Tungsten is super dense?

@Altarious If you want something super-dense, then why not say your alloy is a classified osmium/tungsten/titanium alloy, about as dense as it might get without being a cast-off from an old nuclear reactor.

I had thought about that and while Osmium does mix with Tungsten to make an alloy, it wouldn't be too practical for every person with a suit of Power Armor, granted with the fact that this army is going across the Galaxy, I might not have that many issues with supplies and demand. But I also want the armor to be lightweight, something that can tank hits from most weapons in the setting, but not invincible nor too heavy. I could use the Osmium/Tungsten alloy for my mechs though, those are huge and heavily armored.

I wouldn't use super-heavy materials for wearable armor, since they help against very specific threats. But I'll add a way you could use them.

Ok so I'm curious, you said that armor materials work better when they're lighter except when you against Hypervelocity Rounds. I know it's a long shot scientifically but would that mean that it would be best to just not get hit, aka dodge the round being fired? I could probably get this to work in setting but I guess I just want to know if that would make the most sense realistically?

Easiest way not to get hit is not to be seen. Dodging a round from a long range is possible, but the round itself doesn't know where it's going to hit. In a high-tech environment, you'd probably rely heavily on active camouflage like lasers to confuse guided projectiles.

excellent answer. one note if @Altarious does want the cool-factor superheavy materials: In the "MBT weight class" mechs it might make sense to protect the pilot from direct hits by hypervelocity projectiles. So a bit of special superheavy armor plating that protects the pilot capsule, or maybe even just the head and torso areas of it, could be justified I think.

Ok so active camouflage is something I can do in setting. As for Mechs, yes. Super heavy armor is going to be the norm mostly because those big guys can't really dodge anything but they are going to be able to soak up way more punishment than Powered Armor can.

It might seem silly, but I would think a humanoid tank with sufficient strength and manual dexterity could very well be equipped with an actual, medieval-style shield, only insanely thick and strong. Rather than add heavy ceramics all over the tank-mech, give it a 10 ton boron-carbide pavisse to place  between them and their enemy.

"But it will only be useful if such power-armored troops have a tradition of chivalrously shooting each other in the chest." <- Very good answer on so many levels, but chest shoots are still the most common kill shots in modern warfare, even when not fighting chivalrously.  It does not need to stop 100% of attacks to stop enough to be worth it.

@GoingDurden It's actually not silly at all - guns come with shields, and a tank's turret front is effectively its shield (it's stronger than any other part of the tank). So it can be practical.

@Nosajimiki In gun combat, yes. I was thinking more about missiles, top attack munitions, cluster bombs, etc. But I'll clarify.

Ok this is actually very good. I had thought of giving my PA shields, because Knights, but knowing there's something out there that'll actually work for that is great! As for my Mechs, I'm going to have to see just what all I'd need to make them work because they'd be piloted vehicles rather than something a person wears on the battlefield.

The metric of RHAe ignores/misses a crucial point that separates tanks from mechs: Volume. Because with Titanium-based aerogel-like structures (ideally interspersed with liners, solid but angled plates etc.) you coult attain insane RHAe ratios. It's just currently far too expensive to produce in meaningful quantities and qualities. But while future tanks will basically roll around as deadly floofs, mechs cannot do that because the volume of  let's say arm armor would significantly impact mobility.

@Therac I found out about this and now I'm even more intrigued by armor. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chobham_armour is this the same as your Kinetic Section up above or is that something different?

@Hobbamok What you're describing is a foam-type Whipple Shield. Very weight-effective against chemical and hypervelocity threats, but almost entirely ineffective against hard ceramic penetrators at <2 km/s, aka bullets.

@Altarious Yes, that is it. There are other unusual armor schemes, such as NERA-based armor, used by the French and the Chinese. Soviet tanks heavily feature "textolite", which is a type of fiberglass.

Ahh the Whipple Shield I remember coming across that once. It's an interesting idea for sure, but yeah, not very affective against bullets.

One other thing shields are good for is stealth.  Armored soldiers show up on night vision because their body heat transfers into the armor, but a shield is separated from the body so that it will match the ambient heat of the environment.  This effect can be enhanced with NIR refractive paint so that you not only stop yourself from glowing, but you shield's outline gets blurred making your practically invisible.

@Therac thanks for finding the correct terminology for it (and darn, of course it wasn't a new idea). That being said, I'd expect bullets to be a non-issue due to some strong-enough top layer (that is easily penetrated by >2km/s projectiles.

You are thinking about Armor wrong
The first question you need to ask is:

What is the primary threat that my armor is expected to face

Things that work well against say a Squash-head projectile might struggle against a EFP (Explosively formed penetrator) etc.
The next is that what we know currently is that modern armor systems are not homogenous. Composite armors work by having different materials with different properties that do different things at different stages.
For example:
The outer-most layer might be a very hard facing material, designed to shatter all projectiles that cannot penetrate it.
The next layer might be something like a ceramic material that is designed to disrupt and be highly abrasive to anything that penetrates the first layer.
The next layer might be a mesh or plastic-like layer that is designed to stretch and capture any spalling or fragments that make it through the first two layers.
You then might have an air-gap layer, to allow the first 3 plates a little bit of deformation etc. without passing that energy directly to the next set.
For a walking tank, unless you are using some form of energy shield or other active protection system - you would want a mixture of materials, each designed to complement the others for their weakness.
In short - it is not one magic material that does everything, but layers of different materials that all work to do different things

Ahh ok, so I want a Composite Armor instead of a single layer like modern body armor.

Even modern body (for example level 3 plates) are usually a composite of sort - having a Ceramic plate and a Kevlar weave - the Ceramic is lighter and is good against armor piercing small-arms rounds and the Kevlar is to stop any spalling and catch anything that got through the ceramic plate.

true but the issue with Ceramic plates is that they'd incredibly hard to replace in a post apocalyptic society without the needed materials to really manufacture them on a big scale. So making due with metal plates that last far longer is the best option there, plus IRL metal plates are still used for that very reason, they can take far more impacts without deformation or breaking up like Ceramic does. Although ceramic is pretty good at stopping lasers, so I'm probably still going to use a Composite Armor System in the end

@Altarious You're right that ceramic is much more likely to break than metal, but metal (depending on type) is much more likely to react to the environment and degrade.  You can pull a 3000 year old pottery vessel out of the ground, clean it off, and it'd be in great shape.  3000 year old metal - not so much. Of course, some metals are more reactive than others, but most will rust/corrode/tarnish if damaged and left to sit.  I wouldn't assume that a metal plate would last longer than a ceramic one if left undisturbed. (1/2)

Of course, if there's a finite supply of both and they're being actively used, the metal is going to be more durable (and possibly repairable) than the ceramic.  I wouldn't expect either one to be reproducible in a post apocalyptic society, though.  (2/2)

I've actually found out how to keep most of the equipment I'd need in working order by making giant underground vaults that are sealed away from the elements including air, water, and even radiation. But I do understand what you mean. Although I'm really not sure how long ballistics grade ceramic could feasibly last because I have heard it begins to degrade rather fast when not in use, I could be wrong though not misheard something.

@Altarious  "it begins to degrade rather fast when not in use"  I suspect that you may have got that the wrong way around - I can't see why "not using" a ceramic plate would make it degrade more than having it out in the open?

From what I've read it mostly comes down to what the Plates are made of, how well they're manufactured, and what the backing material is. All of this can have an effect on their shelf life & it's usually not recommended to use them past this time period. Again I may be wrong but usually metal plates have a much longer SL than Ceramic. Granted I do know vacuum sealing can work extremely well for protecting both from the elements.

One interesting option that a Power Armor can use while tanks cannot, is a shield, an actual, medieval style shield held in hand. It could be much thicker than the rest of the armor, and used tactically to be placed in the path of the projectiles, rather than wrapped around the whole user.

@Altarious Ceramic is prone to develop microfractures from moving around which steel and Kevlar do not have an issue with, but in storage, it will last much longer than steel or Kevlar.  The expiration date on body armor is its end of warranty date having nothing to do with an expected breakdown caused by time alone.    Also, mentioning that this is a "post-apocalyptic" world is a big deal.  What you can build, maintain, and restore in such a setting is going to change things quite a lot because most modern armors can't be sourced without access to a global trade network.

I actually did mention it's a post apocalyptic setting a few times but for the most part that's negligible because all of these armors are going to come from before that event. The biggest issue I'm facing is right now what materials would be best for protection against the current threats in setting, which would be Small Arms, Long Arms, Energy Weapons and so on.

There is this concrete, that is pre-stressed, to be more capable to take certain kinds of loads. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P13Mau2VUWw
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prestressed_concrete
Now.. Lets take that concept, and take it to a different material, so its more capable to take extreme brute force of a sharp, local impact.
We could take carbon fiber or some crystal.. or we could take diamond and graphene.
We shape the diamond, on a micro-scopic scale into the equivalent of a almost flattened gothic dome. Then we take grafene to pre-stress it. And because we want that material to be reactive, we embed Piezo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectricity elements into it, that generate electricity, that will make the material contract even further locally on impact.
Finally, we mix it up, we add elements, who are like bowstrings, sapping up energy of the impacting element in the topmost layer. Very similar, though on a smaller scale to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_bow. Ideally, that layer also attaches to the bullet, redirecting momentum.
Summed up: Your bullet comes, penetrates the first layer, and leaves tons of energy in a "sapping" layer, that also should give it a tumble which is almost as good- cause redirected energy is energy we do not need to deflect.
All this leads to something like a a tumbling train, slamming into a fortress hardened by interior stress, similar to gorilla glass or a prince Rupert drop.
Everything else needs reactive armor to defend.

So it's basically best to have a sort of soft armor that hardens on impact with physical trauma?

OP also included laser as weapons against which the armor must work.

Yeah that's kinda why I'm looking for metal which can be polished to shine or coated in a mirror layer to help slow down the lasers. Plus this answer sounds an awful lot like my first layer of protection in the Suits, Nano Mail: An Under Armor Mesh, that doubles as a self sealing pressurized life support glove. This Nano Mail hardens on impact when faced with physical trauma thanks to its Ferromagnetic Gel insulation, keeping most forms of munitions & other kinetic weapons out of the operator, distributing the force of the blow evenly over the users body rendering it harmless.

@Altarious you don't want armor that hardens. It would be like removing the crumple zone of a car, the car (armor) remains intact but the energy of the impact is pushed into the person and electronics behind it, killing them. You want to absorb the blow and stop the bullet simultaneously, not stop the bullet and pass the blow on

@Demigan that's why that particular layer is only one piece of the entire suit, and the part that hardens doesn't stay hard afterwards. It just hardens on impact like real life silly putty and some Ferromagnetic Fluids. That's also why I'm specifically talking about the top most layer being hard so as to stop the actual projectile/shrapnel first. If the top layer doesn't stop it fully then the Gel layer will help catch what's left.

@Pica I am actually curious though, if the surface layer of these plates are made from diamond/crystal, wouldn't that actually help protect from lasers by scattering the beam upon impact, rendering it harmless or at least not as effective as it would normally be?

The best laser defense- is vaping. Basically a tinfoil layer with glycol in between. Hit it, fog- fog kills all lasers, as it soaks up heat into air.

@Altarious that's kind of my point: making it hard during impact is a sure fire way to kill the occupant. Just imagine the crumple zone of a car hardening during an impact. It defeats the purpose. Current body armor is a composite, the outer layer is hard but will break along with the projectile, the layer behind it is ductile and will catch the fragments over a larger area and slow them down over a longer time (still in fractions of a second). So unless the hardened outer armor is designed to also break and let the bullet be caught by a deeper layer, it'll likely kill the user.

Ok so having the soft gel layer also harden wouldn't absorb the impact alongside the metal thus rendering it inert?

You could add something like medical PU Foam to clot and close interior wounds, should something pass through.. also put broken bones into a cast. Also auto-tourniquets

There is a bit of research into liquid armour, is that what you're referring to? @Altarious

Yes actually that's exactly what I'm referring too, except in this case it's a wearable glove that is put on before the Powered Armor skeleton is as an extra layer of protection but also as a way for the Wearer and Armor to interact on a 1-1 basis.

Or .. theoretically, you build a bunker and house the easy damaged organic brain in it- and build a interface to a walking armor conserve without the squishy bits..  sorry humans are just not physically relevant to war anymore. Before anyone says CQB in trenches.. you can build hopping drones, specialized to clearing trenches.

Half of the problem in this discussion is that we do not know what OP means by Power Armor. If its more like a walking Abrams tank that you climb into, then most of the issues above are irrelevant. If it is more like body armor but better, then its near impossible to design a suit of armor to out-design modern projectiles, let alone futuristic ones. At non-ludicrous thickness, modern projectile always wins against armor.

I figured power armor was pretty simple to understand, a suit of armor that's basically a wearable robot with thick plates for protection against most threats of the time period. I consider Mechs to be vehicles you climb into and pilot and not Powered Armor.

Introducing: The Shiva Mark 900 armour. It - is not armoured. At least not conventionally. It has a set of titanium arms/feets, front and back and center trying to be out of the way as much as possible. Each arm has a spear- a spear is a rod, made out- of stacked armour, with several cameras and laser range finders on the side. Think of it as "General Grievous on steroids and annorexia"
If a thread is detected and seen, the shiva - will try to whirl the fragile carrier out of range with minimal harm. If that is to late - which is rare, it will bring a rod in front of the thread. Meaning, any laser/projectile/ always faces a meter of armor with this power-armor. Can be several directions at once.
After that its again getting thrown into cover by your armour.
In rod we thrust and rod we throw..
A spider walks into a mini-gun bullet rain, the mini-gun runs out, the spider does not. Don't be a lumbering knight in shining armour, be a lightning strike in lightweight just in time armour, who sees it coming a mile away and uses a mechanical trophy system.
PS: If you take the brunt force of an attack, thats an energy source, that if redirected, can be used, to accelerate orthogonal way from the bulletstream.

The only problem I see with that, is that in order for this shiva to be able to react to projectiles and RPGs, it would have to move insanely fast. The pilot would be whiplashed to chunky salsa by sudden accelerations and decelerations. There is no possible way to pad or cushion the armor to dampen the effects of inertia at such speeds, the first time the shiva would literally dodge a bullet, the pilot would have their brains scrambled and sprayed out of their ears, because their head just went from moving at sonic speeds to dead stop in a split second, while the brain kept moving.

So make it something autonomous walking with and around you.

why do you need the soldier for then? Just send the shiva piloted like a drone, or entirely autonomous.

Cause mechsuits are roman romantic antics - who want a knight in shining armor, meanwhile the flesh is a liability, political and physical. Its a way to keep the score, there is no COD game, but explain that to a teenager fresh from the server.

Very interesting.
The example of prestressed concrete is good.
For metal it is hardening, i would say. It brings out the best performance of the metal.
For Armoring there exists Hardox600 and similar. Hardox is the manufacturers name for 1.8703, its made by SSAB
https://www.ssab.com/de-de/marken-und-produkte/hardox/produktprogramm/600
In Ukraine they use 4mm Hardox 400 - 600 as wearable Single layer armor.
Its good for military similar 7,62mm projectiles. Ive seen it and it makes a ditch but nothing more.
Combined with 10 LayersCarbon or Aramid behind it should be a light and effective armor.
Maybe a thirdlayer made of 2mm standardsteel helps to catchup small parts that comes trough the two layers.
Dont use aluminium. Under big heat it spreads explosive like hell with temperature of the sun. Try it with a oxygenburner. Then youre roasted.
I used it as a layer for Safes, if a robber will cut it with a oxygenburner he get paid when he hits the aluminium...
I like technical complex things because theyre impressive technology.
But things like a wearable armor should be simple.
And it helps to repair them in field.
Thats only my two Cents.

Simple to wear. Simple to use. Simple to keep semi-functional != Easy to produce. In theory you could handle every infantry unit a tank part on a wheelbarrow and yell "go"..

@Pica, you joke, but a thick shield of ceramic armor on a wheelbarrow, pushed in front of a Power Armor wearing soldier would be very effective.

Lol, I'll be honest I'm thinking of giving these guys Ceramic Plated Shields now because this is a pretty good idea.

Actually, there are a number of armored combat vehicles including the M3 Bradley and M113 that use aluminum alloys.  Armor grade aluminum like 5083 is about  93.5% aluminum, 5% magnesium, and 1.5% other stuff.  You also see non-trace amounts of aluminum in armor grade titanium alloys like Ti-6al-4v.

@goingDurden This is all hypothetical anyway. Anything that would have worked in medieval times does no longer work in a high energy ,high kinetic impacts environment with humans.

Frame Challenge: The strongest material does not mean the best material when talking about future tech defensive systems.
Modern Warfare is Moving towards Active Defenses as the primary defense against modern threats.  Therac's answer is a very good overview of how modern armor currently works and most of the considerations worth addressing with it... but the things about modern armor is that it's being slowly phased out by better and better active defense systems.  If you want to create a future-tech battle suit, it should rely more on ADS and light armor instead of just trying to maximize your physical armor.  An active defense system is a system that prevents an attack from ever hitting you instead of trying to endure its full force when it does.
The Navy has long since given up on the idea of armoring ships because at ship scales, it is far easier and more effective to use a combination of point defense guns, interceptor missiles, jammers, etc.  However, as technology progresses we are seeing these technologies getting smaller, cheaper, more automated, and more effective.  In the wars of the 21st century, we've seen tank armor becoming more and more useless as cheap anti-tank drones and infantry carry weapon systems have gotten good at beating it. In contrast, tank active defenses have significantly improved the survivability of not just tanks against these threats, but light armored vehicles too.  Some newer ADSs have even proven they can deflect or break up kinetic penetrators. In light of this, newer tank designs like the AbramsX program are moving more towards lighter armor and better ADSs.
As this trend continues into the future, we can presume that the future of power armor warfare will not be about carrying exceptional amounts of armor into battle, but to have just enough armor to stop the shrapnel, shockwaves, and fireballs of bullets and RPGs being intercepted by the suit's active defense systems.  Given this, the main considerations of your armor are not what kind of bullets and RPGs it can stop, but what kind of collateral or un-interceptable attacks remain. The good news is that we already have a kind of armor that fits this goal very well.
Use Kevlar or a comparable futuretech polymer
Kevlar flak armors are not made from metal at all because they are not designed to stop bullets and RPGs.  They are made to protect against the explosions and shrapnel of grenades, ricocheting bullets, and near misses from artillery fire which would be the main threat for infantry protected by an ADS.  Kevlar is also highly heat resistant which is why it's also commonly used in making fire fighting turnout jackets.  This means it will resist the fireballs of near target interceptions, and any attempts to use lasers or flamethrowers to overcome the limitations of known ADSs.  It also weighs way less than ballistic armor while achieving all of the goals of an ideal layered defensive strategy.
So, while you COULD slap 500lb of armor on an exosuit, you could also give that same suit an autocannon or RPG that could easily beat a mere few hundred lb of any conceivable armor.  This means that power armor will quickly make the "armor" part of power armor obsolete the second both sides have it.  Instead, you can just give it 50lb of Kevlar and save the other 450lb for tiny automated guns and sensors designed to detect and shot aside any threat that would otherwise need armor before it can reach you, a thermal control system designed to hide you from night vision cameras, and a suite of communication and detection equipment to help you identify and destroy targets before they can even spot you.
This will also work much better with your illustration of what you want your armor to look like.  Your illustration shows an armor that appears to only be 4-5mm thick, yet military grade ballistic plates are typically about 9-25mm thick.  Thinner plates exist, but are only intended to stop low caliber handguns, not military grade rifles.  However, if the "armor" part of your suit is a thermoplastic resin and kevlar fiber composite similar to that used in modern flack helmets, then being just 5mm thick would make since.
A Consideration for Post Apocalyptic Settings.
Since the OP mentioned in comments that this is a Post Apocalyptic settings, this could change everything.  Depending on time elapsed, the armor and its electrical components could be heavily degraded with no good way to replace them.  Even a whole country like Russia is struggling to manufacture anything better than 1970s level technologies when cut off from its global supply chain.  Some guys in a bunker somewhere simply can't make the microprocessors or materials you'd need to repair and restore an old suit of power armor.  This means that unless your setting is within less than 20-30 years of the apocalypse, any power armor you do have is likely frankinstined together and missing some of its original functionality.
So, if your suits' APSs are no longer working, then you may have to strip down these systems and replace them with armor that you fabricate yourself.  If this is the case, then both tungsten and titanium based armor alloys are likely out of the question.  These are both rare metals that require specialised refining and smelting techniques that will be very hard to achieve without a global supply chain.
Chances are you will have access and the ability to work with only a small number of armor grade materials.  4 materials you can scavenge from pretty much any city or town without too much looking around are steel, nylon cloth, fibreglass, and resin epoxy.  Many armored fighting vehicles use just these 4 materials for a cheap armor that can withstand most small arms fire.
Fiberglass is a common household insulation material; so, all you need to do to find it is start knocking out some random drywall.   Resin epoxy can be found is just about any hardware store or carpenter's garage.  Steel is just about everywhere.  Finding it in plates of a good thickness is a bit hard, but its not too hard to forge weld scrap steel into plates if you have a half decent workshop.  Lastly nylon cloth is common in everyday clothing and straps.
To make your armor, start off by patching your degraded Kevlar with Nylon cloth.  Nylon is not quite as good as Kevlar, but it is pretty close.  This will act as a sort of arming jacket to help stop spalling and give your armor room to buckle before it penetrates you.  Next add steel plates they only need to be a few mm thick for the kind of composite armor I am describing.  Then on the outside, layer fiberglass that you glue down with the resin epoxy.  This outer layer will help break up the bullet and distribute the impact.  Fiberglass resin stops bullets very well for its weight.  At just 10-15mm thick, this kind of composite armor can block most small arms fire, and at 30mm thick, it can even stop a 50cal. machine gun, all while weighing only about 1/2 as much as a comparable homogeneous steel armor.

I'm not going to lie I didn't mention it being post apocalyptic because that's mostly a non issue. The story is set quite a while after the event and almost all of the power armor available is only available because of the fact that it's been stored in underground military installations for safe keeping. So it's in pristine condition when the many factions find and begin using them. Plus there's a few AI and Automated Repair Systems in place to keep them in tip top shape, unless they're blown to pieces.

@Altarious It's okay to handwave it away, but if you want hard science, it is important because modern electronics fail over time no matter how you store them.  The parts are so small that quantum tunneling and cold welding cause the shape of the circuits to slowly break, and your HDs slowly lose their charge from disuse so the programs that run it all will get corrupted even faster on a powered down drive than if you are actively using the facility.

Even if you keep it all running with the intention of replacing parts, you'd need a fabrication factory, but those are MASSIVE multi billion dollar facilities with huge logistical needs to supply all off the exoitic equipment and materials that go into them. So no matter what you do, if it takes a computer, it will stop working within a few decades of an apocalypse unless you can re-establish the global trade network.

APSs (and most other advanced military hardware) also need particularly advanced microprocessors which are only produce in one place in the whole world.   No one anywhere else even knows how to make them, much less has the infrastructure to make it happen.

Well that's the thing I have a way of keeping this all running, via the AI being smart enough to be sentient and making deals with people on the surface and keeping things going but that's not entirely within the scope of the question, so I didn't want to add it in and risk my question being too off the topic.

@Altarious I bring it up because my answer is a bit of a frame challenge.  Could bunker people figure out how to make something like tungsten or titanium alloys?  Probably.  But it's far from the best available defense that power armor from a long gone civilization that is more advanced than our own could/should have.  ADS is quickly replacing armor of all sorts already... but what it takes to get/keep it working is WAY harder to stuff into a bunker or to get from trading with less than modern trade partners.

It's not a vault like in fallout, so no one is living in it. It's literally a vault full of ancient war relics to the people on the surface. The AI inside of the vaults takes car of maintaining everything within it and procuring materials. Plus there's plenty of space debris falling back down to earth including meteor's and other material rich resources that the AI's are tracking and collecting. At this point in time earth is very much getting back on its feet, just not to the same degree as it once was. For example there's trains and train networks up and running. Trade routes and so on.

@Altarious the big concern are the silicon monocrystal semiconductors used in modern microchips.  These are not a natural resource, they are synthetic crystals that have to be so pure and flawless that you can cut billions of 20 nanometer lines into them without a single one being broken by a material impurity.  It takes at least the combined global technology and resource availability of the late 1990s to be able to do this.

Technically, you could say that this facility can produce all the computer parts it needs from raw resources without insanely complex supply chains thanks to future tech... but if you have manufacturing tech that advanced, you are looking at a society so much more advanced than us it makes predicting what their power armor would be like rather difficult.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Frame challenge: "strongest" isn't the same as "most difficult to penetrate"
People mis-think armor all of the time. We think that "strength" is an inherent property, like density, but it's really a collection of characteristics.
When a projectile hits a target, it must first provide enough kinetic energy to move the armor out of the way. This is why most things we think of as "armor" are dense materials. While doing this, it fights against the material's tensile strength, which is why most armor has high tensile strength, like steel.
That isn't were it ends, though. You aren't just resisting the energy, you're also trying to spread it out across a larger area. A good example of this is kevlar, which is light-weight, but high tensile strength. It allows the bullet to pull it along, spreading the force out across the length of the fiber before trying to stop it.
Shock wave distribution is quite the science. You're looking to distribute its energy over a large a volume as possible. Other concepts involve carbon fibers laced through shear-thickening materials to convert the energy to stiffen the armor on impact.
Reactive armor takes this to an extreme, using an inch-thick layer of high explosive material. With high explosives, the chemical reaction of the explosion propagates faster than the speed of sound. With reactive armor, the explosion propagates faster than the missile. On impact, it creates an extremely high pressure zone in the path of the projectile that pushes back with more force than any material we can imagine.
Reactive armor spreads the force of an armor-piercing point across several square inches of armor, pushing back against the sides of the projectile instead of just the point. Simultaneously, it has no tensile strength, so it can't be considered "strong".

Its a super-soaker spraying a jet of fluid, just in time into the path of the projectile. Each droplet, becomes a energy obstacle. If it can explode, it deforms the thing flying tremendously. Now lets imagine a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Newtonian_fluid loaded into a trophy like system. It also has to become rigid only during impact and energy soaking. So lets make it a piezzo-crystall substrate embedded in a high pressure explosive fluid that becomes basically a Explosive armor droplet in mid-air. The armor fires a stream of this defense just like a goalkeeper.

Ok this is an interesting idea. So it's basically a wall of explosive liquid that hardens on impact or hardens in mid air. That's actually ingenuous to be honest. Hmm this is giving me ideas because what if this was combined with that bubble gadget that James Bond had in the movie's he used to survive an avalanche? It could in theory provide a very decent amount of protection.

Frame challenge - I don't think "powered armor" means what you think it means.
I will just build upon other answers, because I don't think they focus enough on the requirements.
When you say "My Powered Armor Suits are basically walking Tanks, so I'm using tanks as a basis for their armor.", I don't think you gave enough thought to the concept of the tank - it's purpose and use on the battlefield.
In essence, tanks are big and heavy because they have to be to fulfill their role: unit providing firepower while protected by an armor, working in support or in coordination with other units or in standalone armor units in frontal action (though that last one is basically US alone).
If you want to use your power armor in similar way, then you need to build them accordingly. Think Battletech Elementals' Battle Armor. Or MechWarrior units. Then what you have is, basically, a tank moving on two legs, operated by one man.
Any other use and you should think about them as a tech enhancing individual soldier's capabilities, Combat Jacket Exosuits (all variants), Halo, Iron Man suit or Fallout's T-45/51/55/60 units are somewhere in there.
There's a reason for that, and it's called physics. Tank armor, since WW2 really, is not just hard steel plate. It's a composite, hard on the outside, but soft on the inside. Hard outside is to provide protection against incoming projectiles (both kinetic and high explosive) and soft underside is to provide support for the hard shell and protection in case that shell cracks and stops those cracked pieces of armor to break loose and slice through the crew. Of course, in case of powerful enough projectile penetration through the armor was a given, and then it was either explosive filler in that penetrator or simple kinetic energy (shattering the projectile and sending it in every direction, again slicing through bodies) that was killing the crew. The simplest solution to that problem is to pile on more armor, or add additional armor in layers, with space between them (spaced armor). It's all done in order to slow down the projectile.
If you want to make your armor more like an exoskeleton, you don't have a way to make spaced armor, and additional difficulty is that this armor must be as far away from the body inside as possible, otherwise it will transfer the kinetic energy from the projectile to the user, all without the former making even a dent. The way to mitigate it is to make the armor plates as big as possible, because they will transfer that kinetic energy over a wider area, rendering it harmless to the user. Otherwise it will be just heavy and very clumsy body armor.
In fact, I foresee that exactly type of weapon to be designed specifically to combat battle armor: a projectile that attaches itself to the armor plate of the powered armor and then, using the shaped explosive charge principle, killing the operator inside by exploding and transferring enough of a blast wave inside the armor to turn internal organs into mush. (not my idea - John Ringo's one-shots from "The Empire of Man" series, co-written with David Weber.).
On the other hand, if you want make your infantry more agile, faster, stronger, better protected against "small arms", environmental hazards, enhanced battlefield awareness - in ohter words, enhance individual soldier's capabilities, then power suit is the way to go. Just accept they will not be invincible - just better at surviving, thanks to their ultra modern knight's armor.
Remember, though - for every plate armour someone invented, there is a lucerne hammer awaiting it's turn.
